# Angular 8: No provider for MultilevelMenuService

Tags: angular, npm

I have an angular8 project which I upgraded recently from angular7 on node: "10.15.2","npm": "6.14.5"

I'm using the following plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu

@4.12.2

With `ng serve` the application works fine and the multilevel as expected.

However I've installed angular ssr as described in [universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) and when when I run with the command:

`ng serve --prod --optimization=false`

or

`npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

I receive the following error:

> main.96f1c69496e6c439b888.js:29505 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ListItemComponent -> MultilevelMenuService]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ListItemComponent -> MultilevelMenuService]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for MultilevelMenuService!

I have made the following project in order to show the error I get which you can find in the link [angular8-ng-multilevel](https://github.com/symeonmattes/angular8-ng-multilevel)

Any ideas on how could I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Is your Angular Project having more than 1 module? if yes then did you register the `MultilevelMenuService` in the module in which you are using it/ is the Service available at the root level for all other modules to access it, then ListItemComponent should work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is your fix

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import {
  NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule,
  ɵb,
} from "ng-material-multilevel-menu"; // <------- added from the module
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
// import { MultilevelMenuService } from "ng-material-multilevel-menu/lib/multilevel-menu.service";

const appRoutes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: "serverApp" }),
    NgMaterialMultilevelMenuModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
      enableTracing: false,
      onSameUrlNavigation: "reload",
    }), // <-- debugging purposes only
  ],
  providers: [ɵb], <----- import for service provider
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The issue was your app was trying to get an instance of service which should have been initialised, but was not .hence i added a provider for that seeing the exports in the module.   ɵb <------ a tiny little import a life saver, i don't know why development server was providing with an instance of service... hmmm something to think about...

Comment: I also see that there is missing browseranimationsmodule which is needed for material library its just a error app still loads...